# OpenMP Nested Loop Race Condition for a 3D Volume Array

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, mpi, openmp

I have a hybrid program which has to do some processing on a 3D array, depicting a volume. Each core picks its own part of the volume (MPI), and then uses OpenMP for multithreading. However, when I use the pragma line, there seem to be race conditions and not all parts of the volume are processed. So let's say if I have a volume matrix consisting of 0's, and the function is to add 5 to each cell, I will find that half the cells are empty, and haven't been processed. Below is the bulk of the code. It works perfectly if I do not include the pragma line, which is what is confusing me. Any ideas?

```
for(z=start;z<=end;z++){
    offset=sizeof(int)*(z*r*c);
    fseek(fpIn,offset,SEEK_SET);
    fread(tempbuffer,sizeof(int),r*c,fpIn);

    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) private(x,y,z) schedule(static)
    for(y=0;y<c;y++){
        for(x=0;x<r;x++){
            if(z>=z0 && z<z1 && y>=y0 && y<y1 && x>=x0 && x<x1){
                volbuffer[y*c+x] = proc(tempbuffer[y*c+x]);
            }
            else{
                volbuffer[y*c+x] = tempbuffer[y*c+x]
            }
        }
    }
    fseek(fpOut,offset,SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(volbuffer,sizeof(int),r*c,fpOut);
}
```

Comment: at first glance, `y*r+x` or `x*c+y` looks much better that `y*c+x`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Why is that if I may ask? I've found that this would work for my program

Comment: because you `fread()` `r*c` elements and **not** `(c-1)*c+r`.

Comment: a bigger issue is that `z` is used uninitialized in your loop.

Comment: Ah I forgot to set the ```z``` as shared instead of private.. That fixed it! Thank you so much! You can post it as an answer if you'd like so I can mark it as the correct one

Comment: never mind, this is just a typo. I encourage you to double check `y*c+x` though. If `c=2` and `r>2`, then `y=1,x=0` as the same index than `y=0,x=2`